# Keystone Next not showing database type and always select postgresql by default

Tags: postgresql, keystonejs

I'am new user for using keystone and will create simple project with keystone, but I've some problem when generating project by yarn always select postgresql as default database type.
Below is example screenshot when I'am create new project with keystone next
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/GX4i4.png

Answer (score 0):

The `yarn create keystone-app` command your running uses `create-keystone-app`, documented [here](https://keystonejs.com/docs/walkthroughs/getting-started-with-create-keystone-app). The resultant app simply expects a Postgres database. If you don't already have it, you can [install Postgres using brew](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Homebrew) or [Postgres.app](https://postgresapp.com/) (on MacOS) or one of the [official installers](https://www.enterprisedb.com/downloads/postgres-postgresql-downloads).

If you don't want to use Postgres you'll need to create your project another way. Clone the [Keystone repo](https://github.com/keystonejs/keystone) and have a look at the `examples` directory. It's full of very simply starting points that use an SQLite db instead.

### Sept 2021 Update

`create-keystone-app` has been updated to use SQLite by default now so it won't prompt for a DB connection string at all. You can still switch to Postgres manually if you want but it's a manual step.

The [walkthrough](https://keystonejs.com/docs/walkthroughs/getting-started-with-create-keystone-app) has details.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I trying the instruction and solve my issue, then I already create by manual node init from scratch, and then install dependencies manual way.